# How to start a new console and run a command in it programmatically?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm running tons of experiments and I'm tired of manually opening a terminal and typing:

```
!tensorboard --logdir="C:\Users\OneDrive \Pycharm\DANN MNISTM SVHN\tmp\1561358957553" --host localhost --port 9353
```

to start `TensorBoard`. I want to do this programmatically.

I want to do this in `Pycharm`, or even `Jupyter`. But, I want this to be done in a new notebook / terminal in case of `Jupyter`, not the one I'm currently running cause this will hog the terminal and prevents me from doing extra processing. Same thing in case of `Pycharm`, I want the command above to be run in a new `IPython` console / terminal. Is there a `Python/IPython` way to do that?

Here is what I tried:

```
import os
os.startafile('cmd')
```

But I don't know how to write commands to that newly created window without going to it manually.

I also tried subprocess Popen, but it didn't work, in particular, I created a baby process using Popen but when I call communicate method and send a command it waits for a response! I don't want to wait, there is no any response. I just want to move on to next command.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but I'm not satisifed.

I used os.popen('the command'). It is working fine, but, it keeps sending back updates to my interactive consonle, this clutters it with useless wiritings, tons of them.